# Deduce logical statements

Tags: logic

I have been tasked with coming up with a statement that is true for the following

1. P(4) is true
2. ∀n: p(n) ⇒ p(n+5)
3. Let A={n∈Z|p(n)} be the domain to p(n)

But I am not sure what I can say. For instance, p(n)⇒ p(n+5) only tells me that for each whole number, then I can add 5, and the statement will still be true.

Comment: I am sorry if this might be dumb, but what can I even use ∀n: p(n) ⇒ p(n+5) to do?

Comment: We can't know exactly what your instructor is asking for, but it sounds like they want an *explicit* proposition relating to properties of the integers. Think of some provable properties of sets of numbers eg $\{\ldots,2,7,12,17,\ldots\}$ and try to write these as propositions.

Comment: Trivially: Let p(n) be the statement n > 0

Comment: But what does ∀n: p(n) ⇒ p(n+5) even mean?

Comment: My classmate wrote this, "A = {5k-1 | k∈N}" but I don't understand why it is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments say, you can answer this question inclusive with a trivial answer, the only thing you have to do is to make all the statements above true. Now

$$\forall n: p(n) \rightarrow p(n+5)$$

means that if $p$ is satisfied by a number, let say 1, it has to be satisfied by all numbers $\{1, 6, 11...\}$. Let see a statement that it would makethis statements false: $P =  \{ 5k + 4: k \in N \} \cup \{5\}$. This would make statement (1) true and statement (2) false, for if 5 is in the set, all the numbers {5,10,...} would also have to be.

Now the let see some answers:

(1) Like commented, the statement $P = \{ k>0: k \in Z \}$ would make (1) true, for $4 \in P$, and would make (2) true, for any number $n > 0$ is in $P$, and also the numbers $n$ and $n+5$. (3) also would be satisfied, as we are talking about integers.

(2) The statement $P = Z$ would also turn valid all the statements true.

(3) The statement $P = \{-6, -1, 4, 11, ... \} = \{5k -6: k \in Z \}$.

Comment: It refers to any natural number.